# Can Selenium handle Browser Notifications in the OS?

Tags: selenium

In the screenshot below, I make a VoIP call from an incognito window to an account logged in in a normal Chrome window that is minimised.  Therefore I receive the Chrome notification in the bottom right corner.

I am tasked with creating a *front-end* test to validate the text in the notification window, that would work for Windows, Linux, and MacOS situations.

Now this may or may not be a silly question, but is there a way that selenium can handle tasks related with this notification, for example validating the text that appears in it?  I can't find anything online and I understand it is not a DOM element, so I wonder if it is even possible.  Could someone provide a basic start point for finding this non DOM notification element if it is possible / how to go about testing it in the front end if selenium is not the answer?  TIA.

[Notification example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOQVQ.png)